# How to animate map marker in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, dart, maps, marker

Is there any way to animate map markers in flutter. I am using the official google map plugin. My issue is when the marker position changes it jumps from one location to another. But I want a smooth transition when it changes it's position.

Comment: Have you got any work around this . I am also facing issues in marker moving.